# PowerShell string manipulation on an array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I'm trying to replace all links within an array from this format `"\\domain\share"` to this ``` "<a href=``""\\domain\share"``">\\domain\share</a>" ``` to have it HTML compatible (without the double single quotes, that's a formatting issue here on StackOverflow).

```
$arrayJobError = @()
$arrayJobError = "ERROR | Path doesn't exist: UNC, `"\\doman\Share`""
$arrayJobError += "This path `"\\doman\Share`" isn't right!"
```

I was trying like this `$arrayJobError -match "`\"*`"" but it's not really fool proof and I don't really know what the best way would be to replace only that piece within the array?

Any help is appreciated as I'm a noob in string manipulation.

Comment: Are you trying to extract `"\\domain\Share"` from a string using regex and then format it so it looks like this `"<a href="\\domain\share">\\domain\share</a>"`?

Comment: Yes Raf that's what I'm trying to do. In the end the link needs to be replaced with the correct HTML-code and everything else needs to stay in place. I can also capture my input in a string format (System.Object) first as some kind of `$temp` and then afterwards add the result to the array (System.Array) if that's easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are doing with `$arrayJobError`, the way you define it above `$arrayJobError` becomes a concatenated string rather than array of strings. Here is what I think you are after:

```
$arrayJobError = @("ERROR | Path doesn't exist: UNC, `"\\doman\Share`"","This path `"\\doman\Share`" isn't right!")
$regex = '"(.+?)"'
$arrayJobError -replace $regex, "`"<a href=`"`$1`">`$1</a>`""
```

Result:

```
ERROR | Path doesn't exist: UNC, ""<a href="\\doman\Share">\\doman\Share</a>""
This path ""<a href="\\doman\Share">\\doman\Share</a>"" isn't right!
```

If you are after extracting the paths and adding html tags use this, it will process all matches:

```
[regex]::matches($arrayJobError, $regex).Value | % {
    "`"<a href=`"" + $_ + "`">" + $_ + "</a>`""
}
```

Result:

```
"<a href="\\doman\Share">\\doman\Share</a>"
"<a href="\\doman\Share">\\doman\Share</a>"
```

Comment: I was after the first solution you provided. Thank you again for your help Raf. It's really great to know there are some people out there able to help. I'm sorry for not being more clear, I'll try to do better next (if I can't solve it by then myself).

Comment: There's only one issue, it's having issues with spaces in the path like `\\domain\share 1\share`

Comment: This would also be a problem: `\\domain.net\bnl\DEPARTMENTS\share\share1\SHARE\Target1`, probably because of the multiple slashes.

Comment: It just needs to take everything between the double quotes as a path. I tried with `$regex = '("\\*")'`but it's not giving the desired result.

Comment: Found it: `$regex = '"(.+?)"'`